# Spring AMQP - Duplicate messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am processing a high volume stream ~ 500+ msgs per second, The data is consumed off Spring AMQP+Rabbit using a SimpleMessageListenerContainer with 10 concurrent consumers, I have to do some checks on the Db every 15 mins and reload certain properties for processing, this is done with a quartz trigger which fires every 15 mins, stops the SimplelistenerContainer, does the necessary work and starts the Container once again.

Everything works perfectly when the app starts up, when the trigger fires and the Container restarts, I see the same message being delivered multiple times,this causes a lot of duplicates. There are no exeptions thrown by the consumers.

**The Message Listener**

```
 class RoundRobinQueueListener implements MessageListener {

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) { //do processing
     }

  }
```

**During app startup set up parallel consumers and start the consumer**

```
final SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
       RoundRobinQueueListener roundRobinListener = RoundRobinQueueListener.class.newInstance();
        messageListenerContainer.setQueueNames(queueName);
        messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(roundRobinListener);
        messageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
        messageListenerContainer.setChannelTransacted(true);
```

**The quartz trigger**

```
    void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    messageListenerContainer.stop()
    //Do db task, other processing
    messageListenerContainer.start()
    }
```

Comment: Hi winash, we're going to need to see some code and configuration to help with this.  The relevant Spring config would be a great place to start, as well as the Quartz job code.

Comment: Edited the original question to add code samples, this is more or less how the code is structured

Comment: After some debugging found that the bug was with my stream initialization and I was wrongly blaming rabbit for it, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your messages are now acknowledged by the consumer. If you are not using auto acknowledge mode, you need to acknowledge the message by yourself (This can also be configured at the [SimpleMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html)). Otherwise, the broker presumes that the message was not processed successfully and tries to deliver it again.

Comment: I have set the channel to be transactional, and I have also not set any acknowledge mode explicitly(default is auto).
It does look like an acknowledgment issue but the queue never builds up ie,messages do get processed.

Comment: Is the transaction committed correctly? Enable debug logging in rmq, and check if messages get dequeued.

Comment: @meblow added a comment to my original question, thanks for your suggestions